# iPhone and OpenCV errors using the AV SampleBuffer Output and Face Detection

Tags: iphone, video, opencv, face-detection

Hi fellow Stack Overflow coders,

I've recently been playing around with OpenCV on the iPhone, but have run into a wall and so am turning to you for help. I am familiar with UIKit, Objective C, have used OpenCV for blob detection and face tracking with the Openframeworks C++ framework on a desktop computer.
I am currently attempting to get face tracking working with a real time video stream.

I have got face detection working from this tutorial and sample code using a single image:
http://niw.at/articles/2009/03/14/using-opencv-on-iphone/en

and I have successfully got the data from the video buffer output displaying in a window using OpenGL from a tutorial and sample code (and Apple's example) that I can't actually find the link for right now (will post as soon as I can find it).

I have managed to get edgeDetection of a video stream working with iPhone using the video buffer output by creating an IPLImage from didOutputSampleBuffer and using the standard openCVEdgeDetect and displaying on the screen.

But I can't get Face Detection working, I've tried and tried, but am stuck. Currently I'm just trying to get a single image from the sample buffer passed into the standard openCVFaceDetect methods and then displaying that image with a square (or any marker) around the face. Once I get that working I'll then attempt with a full video stream.

The function that crashes the app is being passed the IPLImage, it then does it's openCV magic and passes this image to a delegate function to be displayed etc

```
- (void) opencvFaceDetect:(IplImage *)aTempOverlayImage  {
cvSetErrMode(CV_ErrModeParent);

IplImage *aOverlayImage = aTempOverlayImage;//[self CreateIplImageFromUIImage:imageView.image];

// Scaling down
IplImage *small_image = cvCreateImage(cvSize(aOverlayImage->width/2,aOverlayImage->height/2), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
cvPyrDown(aOverlayImage, small_image,CV_GAUSSIAN_5x5);


    // Load XML
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"haarcascade_frontalface_default" ofType:@"xml"];
CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad([path cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], NULL, NULL, NULL);
CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

// Detect faces and draw rectangle on them
CvSeq* faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(small_image, cascade, storage, 1.2f, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(20, 20));
cvReleaseImage(&small_image);
[self.delegate parseOpenCVFaces:faces];

// Create canvas to show the results
CGImageRef imageRef = [self getCGImageFromCVImage:aOverlayImage];//imageViewFromOpenCV.image.CGImage;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, 360, 480,
                                                8, 480 * 4,
                                                colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);
CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 480), imageRef);

CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 4);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5);
int scale = 2;
// Draw results on the iamge
for(int i = 0; i < faces->total; i++) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // Calc the rect of faces
    CvRect cvrect = *(CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(faces, i);
    CGRect face_rect = CGContextConvertRectToDeviceSpace(contextRef, CGRectMake(cvrect.x * scale, cvrect.y * scale, cvrect.width * scale, cvrect.height * scale));

    CGContextStrokeRect(contextRef, face_rect);
    [pool release];
}

imageViewFromOpenCV.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(contextRef)];
[self.delegate parseOpenCVFaceImage:imageViewFromOpenCV.image];
CGContextRelease(contextRef);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);
cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade(&cascade);
```

}

I get the error: Thread 1: `Program received signal:"SIGABRT"` at the line:

```
cvPyrDown(aOverlayImage, small_image,CV_GAUSSIAN_5x5);
```

I've looked at the openCV source code and it seems this code shrinks and blurs the image before it is analysed. Although I would love a better explanation from someone who has more knowledge (I've done numerous Google searches). When I comment out this code I get another similar error on the closing bracket of the function.

Am I going about this the right way? I know people have got this working and that many other people would love help with this. Any advice or help with this would be much appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: I managed to get OpenCV working on the iPhone with sample buffer video output after reading this post http://blog.cohen-rose.org/2010/10/over-air-hack-lego-robot-with-iphone.html

Comment: I haven't had time to work out what the actual problem was with my original code, however I will go through and compare the working version with the original and post back. Will also do some optimising and report back for anyone interested in experimenting with this in the future